# Coldfusion convert from UNIX to human readable time without converting the time between the time zones

Tags: coldfusion, timestamp, epoch

i need a conversion from UNIX to human readable time but i don't want to convert the time between the time zones like the following code does:

```
<cffunction name="EpochToDate" hint="Returns Epoch from Date">
    <cfargument name="dateSeconds" default="">
    <cfscript>
        // set the base time from when epoch time starts
        startDate = createdatetime( '1970','01','01','00','00','00' );
        if ( NOT isnumeric( arguments.dateSeconds ) )
            return '';

        // return the date
        // this adds the seconds to the startDate and the converts it to to a local time from UTC format
        return dateConvert( "utc2Local", dateadd( 's', arguments.dateSeconds, startDate ) );
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

For example the timestamp 1532118000 should return the GMT: Friday, 20 July 2018 8:20:00 PM and not server's time zone date.

Comment: What happens when you return without doing `dateConvert()`?

Comment: It returns the conversion in my server's time zone
example: 1532114100

    return dateConvert( "utc2Local", dateadd( 's', arguments.dateSeconds, startDate ) )  = {ts '2018-07-20 23:15:00'}

    return  dateadd( 's', arguments.dateSeconds, startDate ) = {ts '2018-07-20 20:15:00'}

but if you check it here: https://www.epochconverter.com/
GMT: Friday, 20 July 2018 7:15:00 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach you need here is to convert the epoch time from UTC to local first and then do the operation on it. Once that is done you can convert it back to UTC time. I tried this on two servers one is in a forward timezone from UTC and another which is behind.

```
<cffunction name="EpochToDate" hint="Returns Epoch from Date" output="true">
    <cfargument name="dateSeconds" default="">
    <cfscript>
        // set the base time from when epoch time starts
        startDate = DateConvert("utc2Local", CreateDateTime( 1970,1,1,0,0,0 ));
        writedump(startDate);
        if ( NOT isnumeric( arguments.dateSeconds ) )
            return '';

        // return the date
        // this adds the seconds to the startDate and the converts it to to a local time from UTC format
        return DateConvert("local2Utc", dateadd( 's', arguments.dateSeconds, startDate ));
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
<cfdump var="#EpochToDate(1532118000)#">
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.trycf.com/gist/b56872fe0110dce174fc45313c4e4cb9/acf2016?theme=monokai)

UTC +5:30 `{ts '1970-01-01 05:30:00'} {ts '2018-07-20 20:20:00'}`

UTC -7:00 `{ts '1969-12-31 17:00:00'} {ts '2018-07-20 20:20:00'}`